# How to send touch event manually to Canvas or UIElement in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I have a simple canvas with a shape inside :

```
<Canvas x:Name="cnvGameOuter"  Grid.Row="0" >
    <Polygon StrokeThickness="1" x:Name="dashRec"  Height="210" Width="220"  
ManipulationMode="All" Points="80,0,80,130,0,130,0,200,180,200,180,0"  Stroke="#c9c7c7">
    </Polygon>
</Canvas>
```

I want to send touch event to this Canvas or Shape like we're actually touching them. In other words, it is a touch emulation.

```
recognizer.GestureSettings = GenerateDefaultSettings();
// Set up pointer event handlers. These receive input events that are used by the gesture recognizer.
element.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
element.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;
element.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
element.PointerCanceled += OnPointerCanceled;
```

Beside, can I change `PointerRoutedEventArgs` value such as position, device type, ...? They're read-only properties. I want to turn stylus behavior to hand behavior

```
void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    recognizer.ProcessDownEvent(args.GetCurrentPoint(reference));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not a beautiful solution but it works

```
 public MainPage()
 {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //asign default click
        cnvGameOuter.PointerPressed += CnvGameOuter_PointerPressed;
        //or in a xaml
        //<Canvas x:Name="cnvGameOuter"  Grid.Row="0" PointerPressed="CnvGameOuter_PointerPressed" >

 }

  private void CnvGameOuter_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        OGG_PointerPressed(sender, e);
  }

  private void OGG_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        //your action
  }
```

put this where you need it

```
 OGG_PointerPressed(cnvGameOuter, null);
```

or if you do not want a packing of the thing you can use

```
 CnvGameOuter_PointerPressed(cnvGameOuter, null);
```

IMPORTANT

the one problem you can not define PointerRoutedEventArgs and should not be used

Comment: The `PointerRoutedEventArgs` is the one that I focus in. I want to define it my self and pass to `recognizer`. Why I do this? Because the GestureRecognizer of `Microsofts.UI.Input` seem not support multi stylus, but support multi touch instead. Can you suggest any gesture recognition library work in C#?